# vaadin - how to swap components in a grid layout

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin

I have a split panel with an empty panel on the left side and right side is a grid layout. Users can drag elements from the left side and put them on the right side. The right side is a grid layout wth 4,3 matrix.

- We should be able to place components on the right side using drag and drop
- We should be able to swap the components already placed in the grid layout ( right side of the split panel).

I am able to get the first point done. However, I have trouble with the second one.

Also, I tried the Vaadin AddOn for Drag Drop but it does not work for me. SO I am using Vaadin 7.6.4 features of Drag and Drop.

Can anyone help?

```
package com.example.dragdropvaadindemo;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.event.DataBoundTransferable;
import com.vaadin.event.Transferable;
import com.vaadin.event.dd.DragAndDropEvent;
import com.vaadin.event.dd.DropHandler;
import com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.AcceptAll;
import com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.AcceptCriterion;
import com.vaadin.server.Sizeable;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.DragAndDropWrapper;
import com.vaadin.ui.DragAndDropWrapper.DragStartMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.DragAndDropWrapper.WrapperTargetDetails;
import com.vaadin.ui.DragAndDropWrapper.WrapperTransferable;
import com.vaadin.ui.GridLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HasComponents;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;

@Theme("dragdropvaadindemo")
public class DragdropvaadindemoUI extends UI {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long   serialVersionUID = -586508616992840936L;
    final String                LEFT_WIDTH       = "20%";
    HorizontalSplitPanel        splitPanel;
    DragAndDropWrapper          wrapperA;
    DragAndDropWrapper          wrapperB;

    DragAndDropWrapper          splitPaneWrapper;
    Button                      buttonA;
    Button                      buttonB;
    private boolean             isDragMode       = false;
    private static final Logger logger           = Logger.getLogger(DragdropvaadindemoUI.class.getName());

    public int                  rowPosition;

    public int                  colPosition;

    public int getRowPosition() {
        return rowPosition;
    }

    public void setRowPosition(int rowPosition) {
        this.rowPosition = rowPosition;
    }

    public int getColPosition() {
        return colPosition;
    }

    public void setColPosition(int colPosition) {
        this.colPosition = colPosition;
    }

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DragdropvaadindemoUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4605445550539288930L;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        // LEFT SIDE
        EmptyPanel emptyPanel = new EmptyPanel("Left Panel");
        emptyPanel.setId("LeftPanel_0_0");
        emptyPanel.setSizeFull();
        final DragAndDropWrapper wrapperA = new DragAndDropWrapper(emptyPanel);
        wrapperA.setSizeFull();
        wrapperA.setId("Wrapper_LeftPanel_0_0");
        final VerticalLayout leftPanelLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        leftPanelLayout.addComponent(wrapperA);
        leftPanelLayout.setWidth("50%");
        // DragAndDropWrapper leftPanelLayoutWrapper = new DragAndDropWrapper(leftPanelLayout);
        // leftPanelLayoutWrapper.setDropHandler(new DropHandler() {
        //
        // private static final long serialVersionUID = -4676732504780260831L;
        //
        // @Override
        // public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {
        // leftPanelLayout.addComponent(event.getTransferable().getSourceComponent());
        //
        // }
        //
        // @Override
        // public AcceptCriterion getAcceptCriterion() {
        // return AcceptAll.get();
        // }
        //
        // });
        // leftPanelLayoutWrapper.setSizeFull();

        // RIGHT SIDE
        final GridLayout rightPanelLayout = new GridLayout(4, 3);
        rightPanelLayout.setStyleName("csstag");

        // add panels to the layout
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                setRowPosition(i);
                setColPosition(j);

                EmptyPanel emptyGridPanel = new EmptyPanel("RightPanel " + i + "," + j);
                emptyGridPanel.setSizeFull();
                emptyGridPanel.addStyleName("border-gridcell");

                final DragAndDropWrapper rightPanelCellWrapper = new DragAndDropWrapper(emptyGridPanel);
                rightPanelCellWrapper.setSizeFull();

                final int col = getColPosition();
                final int row = getRowPosition();

                rightPanelCellWrapper.setId("Wrapper_EmptyPanel_" + row + "_" + col);
                rightPanelCellWrapper.setDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5729628537182171336L;

                    @Override
                    public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {

                        // source details.
                        Transferable t = event.getTransferable();
                        Component from = t.getSourceComponent();
                        logger.info("wrapper component =" + from);
                        DragAndDropWrapper dragAndDropWrapper = (DragAndDropWrapper) from;
                        logger.info("dragged component count =" + dragAndDropWrapper.getComponentCount() + " with ID="
                                + dragAndDropWrapper.getId());
                        String sourceWrapperId = dragAndDropWrapper.getId();

                        // target details.
                        WrapperTargetDetails details = (WrapperTargetDetails) event.getTargetDetails();
                        logger.info("target component =" + details.getTarget());
                        DragAndDropWrapper dragAndDropTargetWrapper = (DragAndDropWrapper) details.getTarget();
                        logger.info("target component count =" + dragAndDropTargetWrapper.getComponentCount() + " with ID="
                                + dragAndDropTargetWrapper.getId());
                        String targetWrapperId = dragAndDropTargetWrapper.getId();

                        // if the source wrapper id is from outside
                        if ((sourceWrapperId.contains("LeftPanel_")) && (targetWrapperId.contains("Wrapper_EmptyPanel_") ) ) {
                            // EmptyPanel draggedPanelWrapper = (EmptyPanel) event.getTransferable().getSourceComponent();
                            // logger.info("Empty Panel dragged is = " + draggedPanelWrapper.getPanelName() + " with ID="+
                            // draggedPanelWrapper.getId());
                            // logger.info("Empty Panel dragged is = " + draggedPanel.getPanelName() + " with ID=" +
                            // draggedPanel.getId());
                            logger.info("Removing existing component from the location=" + row + "," + col);
                            rightPanelLayout.removeComponent(col, row);
                            logger.info("Adding new component from the location=" + row + "," + col);
                            dragAndDropWrapper.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.WRAPPER);
                            rightPanelLayout.addComponent(dragAndDropWrapper, col, row);

                            // once an empty panel is added, then create a new one in the left side panel.
                            EmptyPanel emptyPanel = new EmptyPanel("Left Panel");
                            emptyPanel.setId("GridPanel_" + row + "_" + col);
                            emptyPanel.setSizeFull();
                            DragAndDropWrapper emptyPanelWrapper = new DragAndDropWrapper(emptyPanel);
                            emptyPanelWrapper.setId("Wrapper_LeftPanel_" + row + "_" + col);
                            leftPanelLayout.addComponent(emptyPanelWrapper);
                            emptyPanelWrapper.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.WRAPPER);
                            emptyPanelWrapper.setSizeFull();
                            // GridPanel_
                        } else if (sourceWrapperId.contains("GridPanel_")  && (targetWrapperId.contains("GridPanel_") ) ) {
                           String sourceRowColStr = sourceWrapperId.replace("GridPanel_", "");
                           String sourceIndexArr[] = sourceRowColStr.split("_");
                           logger.info("sourceWrapperId="+sourceWrapperId + "#sourceRowColStr="+sourceRowColStr + "# row pos="+sourceIndexArr[0] + "# col pos = "+sourceIndexArr[1]);
                        } else {
                            // error criteria.cannot add component.
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public AcceptCriterion getAcceptCriterion() {
                        return AcceptAll.get();
                    }
                });

                rightPanelLayout.addComponent(rightPanelCellWrapper, j, i);

                logger.info("Added panel at location=" + i + "," + j);
            }
        }

        rightPanelLayout.setSizeFull();

        // OVERALL PANEL
        final HorizontalSplitPanel splitPanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
        // splitPanel.setFirstComponent(leftPanelLayoutWrapper);
        splitPanel.setFirstComponent(leftPanelLayout);
        splitPanel.setSecondComponent(rightPanelLayout);
        splitPanel.setSizeFull();
        splitPanel.setSplitPosition(10, Sizeable.Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        splitPanel.setLocked(true);

        final Button dragMode = new Button("Drag Mode On");
        dragMode.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -926098671937004974L;

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                isDragMode = !isDragMode;
                if (isDragMode) {
                    dragMode.setCaption("Drag Mode Off");
                    wrapperA.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.WRAPPER);
                    // wrapperB.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.WRAPPER);

                } else {
                    dragMode.setCaption("Drag Mode On");
                    wrapperA.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.NONE);
                    // wrapperB.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.NONE);
                }

            }

        });

        // outer layout.
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.addComponent(dragMode);
        layout.addComponent(splitPanel);
        layout.setSizeFull();

        this.setContent(layout);
        this.setSizeFull();
    }

    Component findComponentWithId(HasComponents root, String id) {
        for (Component child : root) {
            if (id.equals(child.getId())) {
                // found it!
                return child;
            } else if (child instanceof HasComponents) {
                // recursively go through all children that themselves have children
                return findComponentWithId((HasComponents) child, id);
            }
        }
        // none was found
        return null;
    }

    // find components by type.
    Component findComponentWithNamePattern(HasComponents root, String namePattern) {
        for (Component child : root) {
            if ((child.getId()).contains(namePattern)) {
                // found it!
                return child;
            } else if (child instanceof HasComponents) {
                // recursively go through all children that themselves have children
                return findComponentWithId((HasComponents) child, namePattern);
            }
        }
        // none was found
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the Empoty Panel that supports it.

```
package com.example.dragdropvaadindemo;

import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class EmptyPanel extends Panel{

    private String panelName;

    public String getPanelName() {
        return panelName;
    }

    public void setPanelName(String panelName) {
        this.panelName = panelName;
    }

    public EmptyPanel(String panelName){
        this.panelName = panelName;
        VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(vLayout);
        vLayout.setMargin(true);
        vLayout.setSizeFull();
        Label lblA = new Label(panelName);
        lblA.setWidth("30%");
        //lblA.setDescription(panelName);
        this.setDescription(panelName);

        vLayout.addComponent(lblA);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "We should be able to swap the components already placed in the grid layout ( right side of the split panel)." ? What should hapen and what is currently happening?

Comment: Hi, if componentA  is on location 1,0 of the grid layout while the second one componentB is at 2,0 location of the grid, then the components should exchange their locations. Thus, componentB should be at 1,0 while componentB should be at 2,0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done by using the gridLayout.replaceComponent method.

It would be nice to have a swapping method in Vaadin for the grid layout.